# go to a line and change to uppercase

Tags: c, unix, terminal

I'm trying to do this assignment. Basically there's a file with 10 lines...using argv[] the user enters the filename in location 1 and line number is location 2 of the array.

I got everything working so far...checking file...counting line numbers and so on.

What would you guys suggest that I do to change the characters on that line to upper. I'm lost with how to do it. We can only use lseek, open, write, read and close commands.

My logic was ... if the user enters 5 for line number to change....in program I count the line numbers....when the counter hits 4..anything after that is line 5...up until \n.

The counter increments on each \n it comes across.

```
 int line;
  int counter = 0;
  char c;
  do
  {
    line = read(fd, &c, 1);
    if (c == '\n')
    {
      counter++;
    }
    if (lnum == counter)
    {

    }
  } while (line != 0);
```

Comment: Use a function which reads a whole line, such as `fgets`. You don't need to look for '\n' yourself because the function is responsible for this already.

Comment: using f commands like fopen and stuff isn't recommended. Don't know why. Just our lecturer wanting us to use and think more on the commands i specified

Comment: Well, why don't you try the method you outlined in your question? Is there a specific part of it that is causing difficulty?

Comment: Do lines have a fixed length?

Comment: lines can be any lengths. I can't seem to see what to put in the if statement when I reach the \n on previous line. at the momment I have what i edited in question

Answer (score 1):

You are just going to change the line, keeping it with the same size, so you can overwrite it(no need to rewrite the file). Since you have already found the way to read the lines you know the position where your line starts (in number of bytes, thanks to read function). 
So you read the line you have to change to uppercase, you reposition the position indicator to the beginning of the line (using lseek) and then you rewrite the reading line with the changes you want.

Comment: How would you reposition lseek at the start of this line. Thats whats baffling me

Comment: You have to already know where the line starts, because you had to find the line the first time. The `lseek()` function can be used to reposition the file handle to a specific point in the file, which is the start of the line which you already know.

Comment: Well you have two ways in the first you can count the number of bytes you read from the file till you reach the beginning of the line you want to change. In your source code it seems you are reading one byte at a time read(fd, &c, 1); (or char if you prefer). So imagine you read x bytes (chars) before you reached the line you want. Then to rewrite the line just call lseek with the right arguments in this case: lseek(fd, x, SEEK_SET); SEEK_SET because you measured it from the beginning of the file.

Comment: that x would represent the number of bytes read? SO would I create another counter for each byte read, then pass that into lseek

Comment: In the second option, you read the file when you reach the line you want, you read it and while you do that (or after by using strlen) you can count the number of bytes (chars) that this line contains (lets say x). Then you just need to move the position indicator x bytes backwards counting from the position your indicator points after you finish read the line. So in this case you do lseek(fd, x, SEEK_CUR);

Comment: No, you just start in x=0 and for each char you read, you increment the x till you reach the beginning of the line you want.